# SQL SP fast in SQL Slow from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following SQL SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mysp

@HCPID varchar(10),
@From datetime,
@To Datetime,
@LoadType int
with recompile
AS
BEGIN
set arithabort on;
set nocount on;

begin
Select appt.*,
t1.StoreID,
t2.AppointmentDate,
t2.DoctorID,
t2.LoggedInUserID,
t2.Serial,
t2.TimeIn,
t2.TimeOut,
t3.FName,
t3.LName,
t3.AR_FName,
t3.AR_LName,
t3.MName,
t3.MotherName,
t3.AR_MName as Ar_MName,
t3.AR_MotherName as Ar_MotherName,
t4.ID as VisitID,
t5.Flag,
t5.FlagDate,
convert(date,'1900-1-1') as AdmissionDate,

convert(date,'1900-1-1')as DischargeDate

from cms.Appointments as appt
left join CMs.t1 on appt.ID = t1 .AppointmentID
left join CMs.t2 on appt.ID = t2.AppointmentID
left join CMs.t4 on t4.AppointmentID = appt.ID
left join CMs.t5 on t5.


AppointmentID = appt.ID

    inner join CMs.t3 on t3.ID = appt.PatientID



    where  appt.UserID = @HCPID
     AND  ( CONVERT(varchar(10), StartTime, 112) >=  CONVERT(varchar(10), @From, 112) OR (IsNull(@From, 0) = 0))
  AND  ( CONVERT(varchar(10), StartTime, 112)  <=  CONVERT(varchar(10), @To, 112) OR (IsNull(@To, 0) = 0))

    and ShowInSchedule = 1
end
```

if I run the SP from SQL it takes 1-2 secs, if I call it from C# using the same parameters values, it takes about 10 secs, and sometimes I get one of the following messages.
[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lpWp.png)
[Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39mlK.png)

I call it from C# as below:

```
string commande = "mysp";
CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DbHelper.CommandTimeOut = 0;
DbParameter[] dbParameter = new DbParameter[4];
dbParameter[0] = DbHelper.CreateParameter(Settings, "@HCPID", ent.UserID);
dbParameter[1] = DbHelper.CreateParameter(Settings, "@From", ent.StartTime);
dbParameter[2] = DbHelper.CreateParameter(Settings, "@To", ent.EndTime);
dbParameter[3] = DbHelper.CreateParameter(Settings, "@LoadType", LoadType);

list = DbHelper.ExecuteList32<AppointmentsViewEnt_1>(Settings, commandType, commande, dbParameter);
```

**UPDATE**

Please note that if I use the same application with the same code at another client it running normally, and I never encounter the same error. This error happens only at one client.

**UPDATE**

SQL Profile Data:

- CPU  2479     Reads 31791  Write 0      Duration 3578       StartTime
  14/06/2016 22:33:30    EndTime 14/06/2016 22:33:34

Comment: Are you sure that you are hitting the same database?

Comment: Are you accessing a remote server or connecting to localhost? and is your connection string correct?

Comment: yes, the same database..

Comment: Connecting to a remote server

Comment: How much data is being returned? Depending on where you call it from this could make a difference. How are you calling it from c# (you did not provide any code)? This could also make a difference. Finally what type of Sql install is this (MSSql, Sql Lite, something else) and how are you connecting to this in both instances (Management Studio, ADO.NET SqlConnection)? Finally have you done any profiling to see where the lag is when calling it from c#? You can profile using sql tools and visual studio tools. Maybe the problem is not with the SP at all.

Comment: I updated the code to show how I am calling from C#.

Comment: 9 rows are being returned.it is MSSQL. what should I check when I profile from SQL or visual studio?

Comment: Do you get the error everytime you call it? or just sometimes and rest of the times you get the result as expected?

Comment: In sql server use Sql Server Profiler. You can access this from the Sql Server Management Studio. You want to know Duration, CPU, Reads, Rowcount, TextData, Application Name. This will tell you the actual performance stats of the query on Sql Server. Then you can rule out if its the database or the code.

Comment: When you say, "run the SP from SQL", do you mean SQL Server Management Studio? What does the `ExecuteList32` function do internally? Is that user code? Is it using reflection to populate the object from a `DataReader` or `DataAdapter`/`DataSet`? In this case, that might be the bottleneck. Connecting with the same credentials/trusted connection from both SMSS and .NET?

Comment: How are you measuring 10 seconds in the code? You should do it at the point that the ADO.NET `SqlCommand` calls `ExecuteReader` (or other Execute method on a `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataAdapter`). Do not measure the time it takes to do all the other stuff like mapping results back to your object graph.

Comment: I get the error sometimes,and sometimes I get the result."run the SP from SQL" means from the SQL server management studio,The ExecuteList32 () just map data, it has nothing to do with SQL, and all the exception returned are of type SQLException

Comment: ok... I do not believe that the `ExecuteList32` function just maps data. It gets the `DbCommand` instance as an argument, so the actual execution must take place in there. Could you show the code around `ExecuteReader` or `Fill` or whatever it is, inside that function? Also, the second exception shows that there might be a problem with `Connect` as well... could you show the code where the connection is opened?

Comment: @dlatikay ..please see the update of the question...no i don't have the code, and I use the same method else where in the code.

Comment: I understand. Still, then it is a black box. All relevant action (opening the connection, executing the command) takes place in there. focus on profiling, then...

Comment: Without seeing what `DbHelper.ExecuteList32` does it will be really hard to help. Is `DbHelper` a public library we could look in to the documentation for?

Comment: It seems that the problems you're experiencing are associated with network issues. When you run the command from SS MS, are you logged into a machine that is "closer" to your instance of SQL Server? What about the two clients? Where are they relative to one another and the respective instances of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks all, yes I think it is related to network, because checked another functions, and also slow.. Do you have any idea about what to check?

Comment: You mean what to check for the specific source of the network issues? WireShark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your kind help.
After hours of searching and troubleshooting, It was the SQL 2008R2 corrupted! I installed SQL 2014 and all went good, the memory decreased from 10 GB to 5 GB! and the CPU load is less than 20% most of the time(Although on some situations it loads to 70% but rare cases and I will check my code again)

Answer (score 0):

To add more details for any future seekers this problem may happen from what called parameter sniffing, and can be solved by adding `with recompile` to the stored procedure such as :

```
create procedure mysp

@par varchar(100
with recompile
as 

-- def of SP goes here
```